# AJAX w/ rails and using ajaxStart and ajaxStop

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using rails to handle ajax requests for change between menu tabs on my homepage. I tried adding in a new function to hide and show a ajax spinner depending on when ajaxStart and ajaxStop is called, I can't seem to get it working. If this because I'm making ajax calls through rails and shown below? How can I get this going? Thanks a lot for any help.

### application.js

```
$(function() {
  $('#loading').ajaxStart(function() {
    $(this).show();
  }).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

### Users controller

```
def bookmarks
 @bookmarks = ...
 respond_with @bookmarks
end
```

### Views/users/bookmarks.js.erb

```
$('#stream').html('<%= escape_javascript(render("posts", :posts => @bookmarks)) %>');
```

### layout

```
<body>
...
<div id="loading">
  <p><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" /> Please Wait</p>
</div>
</body>
```

### css

```
#loading { 
     display:none;
     position:fixed;
     left:0;
     top:0;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     background:black;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used rails so I don't understand/see where your ajax call is happening. That said, your syntax for ajaxStart and ajaxComplete looks fine to me.

Here's a working example using jQuery's typical ajax function (which I assume rails is using under the hood if you're expecting ajaxStart and ajaxComplete to work.

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/MNd5h/1/

HTML

```
<div id="loading">
  <p>Please Wait</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#loading").ajaxStart(function() {
    $(this).show();
}).ajaxComplete(function() {
    var $loading = $(this); 
    setTimeout(function(){
        $loading.hide();
    },1000); //Timeout so you can see the loading happen
});

$.ajax({
    url: "/echo/json/"
});
```

CSS

```
#loading { 
     display:none;
     position:fixed;
     left:0;
     top:0;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
 }
```